# Integration problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to solve this integral including the `MeijerG` function using Mathematica :

```
Integrate[
 x^((a*b/2) - 1)*
  MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0}, {}}, (b *x^(l/k))/r^(
   a/2)]*(z - x)^((a*b/2) - 1)*
  MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0}, {}}, (b *(z - x)^(l/k))/r^(a/2)], {x, 0, z},]
```

But, it keeps giving me the same integral I write as follows:

```
Integrate[
 E^(-b r^(-a/2) x^(l/k) - b r^(-a/2) (-x + z)^(l/k))
   x^(-1 + (a b)/2) (-x + z)^(-1 + (a b)/2), {x, 0, z}]
```

What can i do to get the output of this integration??

Comment: Are you even sure that there's supposed to be a closed form entirely in terms of Meijer $G$?

Comment: With the explicit settings `{a = 1, b = 1, k = 1, l = 2, r = 1}`, it still returns the `Integrate[]`, which indicates that *Mathematica* does not know how to solve it (at least in that form).

Comment: Rubi (apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich) cannot do it, either.

Comment: does it mean that the integral has no answer??

Comment: All it means is that there might indeed be one, but *Mathematica* is not sufficiently capable to find it.

Comment: so it can be solved but only manually, right?? i mean using some tables of integrals...is this the only way?

Comment: Do you have some constraints perhaps?

Comment: this is my question but i couldn't enter my account, i don't know why!!
actually the only constraint could be that GCD[l,k]=1
this is a convolution problem between two alpha-mu random variables

Comment: I was more thinking about domain restrictions, for instance, is `z` Real?

Comment: Please go [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged so that you can reclaim your question.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
$Version

(* "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" *)
```

the integral does have a symbolic solution for `k == l` (and the spurious comma deleted from just before the final bracket).

```
Integrate[(x^((a*b/2) - 1)*MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0}, {}}, (b *x^(l/k))/r^(a/2)]*
    (z - x)^((a*b/2) - 1)*MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0}, {}}, (b *(z - x)^(l/k))/r^(a/2)]) /. 
    k -> l, {x, 0, z}]

(* ConditionalExpression[(E^(-b r^(-a/2) z) z^(-1 + a b) Gamma[(a b)/2]^2)/Gamma[a b], 
   Re[a b] > 0 && Re[z] > 0 && Im[z] == 0] *)
```

This solution is not as general as that requested but may still be of use.

Comment: I guess it should be noted at this juncture that OP's integral is an autoconvolution integral…

Comment: i copied and pasted your integration but i didn't get your answer, i got the same integration again!!!

Comment: why it keeps giving me the same integration?!!

Comment: What version and OS are you on, @dalia?

Comment: i have Mathematica version 9

Comment: may be it's the problem of not getting the answer, right??

Comment: @dalia, again, it's possible that version 9 is not sufficiently able to handle your integral.

Comment: yes,  i think that too, Thank you, i will get the latest version and try again.

Comment: I tried doing it on version 10.0 but it doesn't work...did any one try to do it using version 10??

Comment: @dalia  My answer used 10.4.1.  I have added version information to the answer to clarify this.

Comment: yes, i know that, but i thought that may be 10 can do it.

Comment: does it work if k==2??

Comment: @dalia  My solution is for `k -> l`, not `k -> 1` (the letter, not the number).  I does not work for `k -> 2` either.

Comment: ooh, okay i see